# Pointcloud to Model with CGAL complete beginner, Tutourial? Guide or tips?

Tags: cgal

I've stumbled upon CGAL and it seems amazing.

Anyone know of any simple ways I can test some of it's magic out without knowing any prior C++ or programming? Or a really thorough guide?

Just to get you an understanding of my general tech level(unrelated to CGAL) I know printf.. prints.. stuff.. but I have no idea how to put that into practice. And I've managed to install npm modules by slamming commands into cmd and run a module afterwards.

If there's no easy beginning to get a taste of this, other tips is also welcome if I have to take a longer route to understanding this.

What I want to achive is my input is pointcloud data scans -> magic/CGAL/ -> 3D models is my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the 3D polyhedron demo that contains most of the functionalities of CGAL.
You can compile it yourself by compiling the code in `demo/Polyhedron` from a release or use the pre-compiled windows demo available: [demo](https://www.cgal.org/demo/5.0.1/polyhedron_3.zip) + [dlls](https://www.cgal.org/demo/5.0.1/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip) to be extracted in the directory of the demo.

Also [here](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/~sgiraudot/Reconstruction_v3/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html) is a WIP version of a tutorial that should be integrated in the official documentation soon.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and wrestle with this :)

Comment: hi,  is any new version about the demo app?  the demo always crash while use surface reconstruction

Comment: Try https://www.cgal.org/demo/5.5/polyhedron_3.zip